# Sequence of keypresses crashes tmux

Tags: tmux

When I type `C-b :` to get to the command prompt, hitting escape and then quickly hitting any (or most) other key will cause tmux to indefinitely pause on the status bar. If you press enter, you can get back to tmux, but if you pres any two alphanumeric keys will cause the tmux server to crash. I have tried this on both `set -g status-keys vi` and `set -g status-keys emacs` as well as `set -o vi` and `set -o emacs` in bash. None of them seem to have an effect. I got my coworker to replicate this on his machine, so it doesn't seem like it's only me. What's up?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems to be fixed in the very newly released (11 hours ago) tmux 3.3!